# Cannot access email section of settings

Tags: craft3, control-panel

I somehow can't access the email section of settings;
/admin/settings/email

```
Argument 1 passed to craft\helpers\MailerHelper::createTransportAdapter() must be of the type string, null given, called in ___/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/SystemSettingsController.php on line 139
```

Everything is up to date, and I've tried disabling all plugins.

Any tips on how to fix this?

I don't think I previously have added any email settings to the site, so it should have been a clean slate.

Comment: Have you tried running `./craft project-config/rebuild`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Olivier. Unfortunately didn't work, but I also have useProjectConfigFile set to false. Forgot to mention that. Is it any way to rebuild the whole craft install via CLI? Or possibly empty certain db-tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in dev or back up first.

Set `'useProjectConfigFile' => true,` in your `config/general.php` and refresh your Control Panel. This will place a `project.yaml` file in your `config/` folder.

Open that file and look for a portion that looks like this:

```
email:
  fromEmail: your@email.com
  fromName: Sitename
  transportType: craft\mail\transportadapters\Sendmail
```

If only your `transportType` is empty, add `craft\mail\transportadapters\Sendmail` as above (you'll be able to change that later if needed). If more is missing, set at least what you see above and if you have no `email` section at all, add it.

Save the file then refresh your Control Panel. It should say *Changes to project.yaml must be applied to the loaded project config.* Hit the **Sync changes** button.

Next, check if you can access your mail settings again and if so set `'useProjectConfigFile'` back to `false`.

Comment: Thanks Olivier! This solved it.